# Não consigo acessa o índice de um for dentro do addeventlistener

Tags: javascript, html

```
   docReady(function () {
    var arr = ["usuario/cadastroum"];
    var lis = document.querySelector(".metro").getElementsByTagName("li");

    for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
        lis[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
            console.log(i);
            if (arr[i]) {
                apontar(arr[i], false);
            }
        });
    }
   });
```

No `console.log` aparece 5 (Pois existem 6 **<li>**), seja o primeiro, o segundo, o terceiro, etc...
Quando eu clicar na primeira **<li>**, quero que apareça 0 e não 5, porém, sempre aparece 5, pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso se deve ao problema de escopo do `var` no seu loop onde tem o `for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++)`, [leia mais sobre isso](https://imasters.com.br/desenvolvimento/escopos-em-javascript).

Mas basicamente o que acontece é que a cada iteração do loop, voce acaba redefinindo o valor do `i` por causa do problema de escopo.

Acho que simplismente substituindo `var` por `let`, resolve seu problema. Ficaria assim seu código:

```js
docReady(function () {
    var arr = ["usuario/cadastroum"];
    var lis = document.querySelector(".metro").getElementsByTagName("li");

    // for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
    for (let i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
        lis[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
            console.log(i);
            if (arr[i]) {
                apontar(arr[i], false);
            }
        });
    }
   });
```

Faça os testes e me diga se resolveu.

Saiba mais:

- *[Como funciona o var, let e const?](https://medium.com/collabcode/javascript-e-suas-vari%C3%A1veis-var-let-e-const-b035b44c2dab)*

Comment: Cara, não sei como agradecer, muito obrigado! não sabia dessa diferença! +1

Answer (score 3):

Trocar `var` por `let` até resolve e sim, o uso disso esta correto, mas a questão nesse ponto é que o problema principal é tentar pegar algo que nem *"existia mais"*, quero dizer, no `var i` quando acessou `apontar(arr[i], false);` ele pegou o valor conforme a ultima operação do loop, isso poderia ser simplesmente resolvido isolando em uma função e usando o `this`, por exemplo:

```js
var arr = ["usuario/cadastroum"];
var lis = document.querySelector(".metro").getElementsByTagName("li");

for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
    lis[i].addEventListener("click", apontarClick);
}

function apontarClick() {
    apontar(this, false);
}

function apontar(elemento, acao) {
    console.log(elemento, acao);
}
```

```css
.metro li {
    padding: 15px 5px;
}

.metro li:hover {
    background: #fc0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="metro">
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>3</li>
   <li>4</li>
   <li>5</li>
   <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

Dessa forma até isola e facilita possíveis manutenções futuras no código.

Você também poderia usar `Event.currentTarget` para pegar o elemento associado ao evento, como no exemplo passamos o parâmetro `(e) =>`

```
for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
    lis[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => apontar(e.currentTarget, false));
}
```